# Should I generally prefer named packages to unnamed ones?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Usually I put all my classes to unnamed packages because:

[+] MXMLC requires main class to be in unnamed package.
[+] No need to write additional imports.
[+] My applications are relative small (10-15 classes), so I prefer to keep all my *.as in src/ without subfolders.

What are the benefits of using named packages for small projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is useful you to read this :

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_05.html